# Javascript if statement issue, and how one can verify a color in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a tic-tac-toe game. The rules are the same, there is a red player and a blue player. Only difference is on a player's fourth move, their 1st box will revert back to white, so each player can only have a max of three marked boxes marked as theirs (red or blue).

This is my html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="game.css"/>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="game1.js" ></script>
      <title> TicTacToe </title>
    </head>
  <center>
    <body>
      <h1> Tic Tac Toe! </h1>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><canvas id = "canvas1" onclick="canvasClicked(1)"></canvas></td>
          <td><canvas id = "canvas2" onclick="canvasClicked(2)"></canvas></td>
          <td><canvas id = "canvas3" onclick="canvasClicked(3)"></canvas></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><canvas id = "canvas4" onclick="canvasClicked(4)"></canvas></td>
          <td><canvas id = "canvas5" onclick="canvasClicked(5)"></canvas></td>
          <td><canvas id = "canvas6" onclick="canvasClicked(6)"></canvas></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><canvas id = "canvas7" onclick="canvasClicked(7)"></canvas></td>
          <td><canvas id = "canvas8" onclick="canvasClicked(8)"></canvas></td>
          <td><canvas id = "canvas9" onclick="canvasClicked(9)"></canvas></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <button type="button" id = "reset">Reset</button>

    </body>
  </center>

</html>
```

The accompanying Javascript:

```
//Global variables
var winningCombinations= [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]];
var turn = 0;
var theCanvas;
var c;
var d;
var y;
var playerRed;
var playerBlue;
var color;

//instanciate Arrays
window.onload=function(){

    playerRed = new Array();
    playerBlue = new Array();

}

//Game methods
function canvasClicked(canvasNumber){
    theCanvas = "canvas" + canvasNumber;
    c = document.getElementById(theCanvas);

    if (c.style.color = "white") {
        if (turn%2 == 0){
            //c.style.background = "red"; // red goes first, start at turn=0
            $("#" + theCanvas).css("background-color", "red");
            playerRed.push(canvasNumber); // adds canvas id to array
        }
        else {
            $("#" + theCanvas).css("background-color", "blue");
            playerBlue.push(canvasNumber); 
        }
    }

    //either color has 3 colors on the board, change the least recent back 
    //to white, as per the rules
    if (turn%2 == 0) {
        if (playerRed.length > 3){
            theCanvas = "canvas" + playerRed[0];
            //d = document.getElementById(theCanvas);

            $("#" + theCanvas).css("background-color", "white");
            playerRed.shift();
        }
    }
    else {
        if (playerBlue.length > 3){
            theCanvas = "canvas" + playerBlue[0];
            //d = document.getElementById(theCanvas);

            $("#" + theCanvas).css("background-color", "white");
            playerBlue.shift();
        }
    }

    //check if game is won, first sets currentPlayer
    var currentPlayer;
    if (turn%2 == 0) {
        currentPlayer = playerRed.slice();
    }
    else {
        currentPlayer = playerBlue.slice();
    }

    //Loops through the winngingCombo's and compares them to that of 
    //Current player's. If they are ==, then alert and give option to reset
    if (currentPlayer.length == 3){
        for (var i = 0; i < winningCombinations.length; i++){
            if (are_arrs_equal(winningCombinations[i], currentPlayer)){

                if (turn%2 == 0){ //setting color, for the alert() below
                    color = "Red";
                }
                else {
                    color = "Blue";
                }
                alert(color + " Won!");
                playAgain();
            }
        }
    }
    //increment turn #
    turn++;
}

//jquery reset function, uses reset function from below
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        playAgain();
    });
});

//reset function
function playAgain() {
    y = confirm("Reset?");

    if (y == true) {
        alert("Lets play again!");
        location.reload(true);
    }
    else {
        alert("fine");
    }
}

//compares two arrays, even checks for type! 
function are_arrs_equal(arr1, arr2){
    return arr1.sort().toString() === arr2.sort().toString()
}
```

I do have a css file but it is small and just defines the canvases to have a background of "white".

My issue is this: in the javascript code, my first if statement, for the function canvasClicked, is not correct:

```
if (c.style.color = "white") {
```

I think it should be

```
if (c.style.color == "white") {
```

It works with the single `=` but not when I make it double equals `==`, why is that? (also, what is it checking for in `if (c.style.color = white)`? Is it checking it has a color, or setting it to white? both?) When it only has a single `=`, it is not checking that it's white, so I can click it once, make it red, then click it again to make it blue. That should not happen with `==`; but with `==` the canvases just stay white.

Also, I'm trying to implement jQuery, so I'd like to change the first if statement further to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("canvas").click(function(){
        if ($(this).css("background-color) == "white"){
```

However, I have no success with that, I've also tried:

```
if ($(this).css("background-color) == "rgb(256, 256, 256)"){
```

Also with no success. I've added an `alert($(this).css("background-color))` to make sure I was clicking the individual canvases (it seems I was as an alert/popup box does appear after clicking), but it seems the if-statement is never invoked. I figured it probably has something to do with the if statement not working.

Any feedback/suggestions would be appreciated. Also any suggestions to other parts of the code would be great as well. Thank you.

Comment: `if (c.style.color = "white")` overrides the value of c.style.color and that successfully, the result: true

Comment: The `=` in your if statement **sets** the value of `c.style.color` to `white` whereas `==` checks **if** your `c.style.color` is `white`.

Comment: The return value of an assignment (=) is always the assigned value. In your case the stripped if will look like `if ("white")`. In JS this will be handled as true.

Comment: thanks guys, so any suggestions on why the if statement does not work when I put `if (c.style.color == "white")`, as in the white canvas does not become red/appear to do anything? I just tried changing it to `c.style.background` but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I investigate the issue, I found that your statement "c.style.color" OR "c.style.backgrounColor" always return empty value. That's why  your if condition not working properly.

you just need to add one more OR statement in your if condition just like below and it's works fine.

```
   if (c.style.backgroundColor == "white" || c.style.backgroundColor == "") {
}
```

Thanks and please mark it correct if its helpful to you.

Comment: wow thank you! Why do you think that is? I set the canvas's background to `background: white` in the .css. This is really interesting. Thanks! It works now.